# "Access violation reading location" Thrown From Empty DLL Method

Tags: c#, c++

I am getting the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x71D1336E (vcruntime140.dll) in My Test App.exe:
> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00974000.

When calling the following method from C# .NET Framework console (this is a C++ DLL unmanaged project):

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int SetIpAddress() {
        return 0x8;
    }
}
```

This is my console code:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\Dash\\Release\\Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int SetIpAddress();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = SetIpAddress();
        Console.WriteLine($"SetIpAddress result: {result}");
    }
}
```

From all the similar SO questions relating to "access violation reading location," it relates to issues with allocating memory. But, as you can see, there is no memory being allocated in any of the methods. Thoughts?

Comment: The names don't match `SetNcIpAddress` vs `SetIpAddress`. Typo ?

Comment: @RichardCritten - yes, SetIpAddress - the method names match up, that was just a typo.

Comment: Is the DLL 32-bit while your C# is 64-bit? I believe I ran into this once because of that.

Comment: Is this also a typo `...Dash\\\\Release...` ?

Comment: Both projects are 64-bit releases. And, yes, the directory path was also a typo.

Comment: @bschellekens - you were on the right track. The issue was that the DLL was a DEBUG compile, but the console was looking at RELEASE. When both are RELEASE builds, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a mistake in target builds - one was DEBUG, the other was RELEASE.

@bschellekens comment helped me figure this out. Thank you!